# How can I prevent iTunes from auto starting when I plug in an iOS device?

Tags: itunes, apple-configurator

i know we already have topics about it, but i did not found my solution.

So i don't want to start iTunes, when i plug in iDevices. We have like 300 iPads, and i am using the configurator. iTunes still starting automatically, even when the Configurator is running.

I really don't want to turn off this settings under the iPad summary screen one by one. I have already turned off the autosync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem you're experiencing is that the iPad connections trigger a New iPad activation dialog, you can turn this off by typing this terminal command **when iTunes is not running**:

```
defaults write com.apple.iTunes StoreActivationMode -integer 1
```

You can turn on the new iPad Activation dialog with this command:

```
defaults delete com.apple.iTunes StoreActivationMode
```

Remember, iTunes cannot be running when either of these commands is run.

Comment: This has a very unpleasant side-effect if used on your regular iTunes & regular phone - a never-ending cycle of 'trust this computer?' Yes. "This phone has already been activated & may be disconnected." (which also deletes any existing backups from MobileSync) I'm glad I remembered this post & looked it up again.

Comment: That's the wrong defaults key.   The correct command is 

    defaults write com.apple.iTunesHelper ignore-devices 1

Comment: My original answer was from **2015**. Perhaps Apple has changed the structure of the .plist file -- they do that all the time. In 2015 and 2016, I needed to use this command when I used Configurator on many iPads. I now have JAMF Casper and my life is so much better.

Answer (score 2):

Run this command in a terminal to disable that behavior:

```
defaults write com.apple.iTunesHelper ignore-devices 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know to not have to set it for each & every device individually is to disable the iTunesHelper app from Users & Group control panel

[image]

picture source http://www.redmondpie.com/disable-automatic-itunes-launch-when-iphone-is-connected-to-windows-or-mac-how-to/